# Compiler not found when building with SCons

Tags: bash, sh, ubuntu-18.04, scons

I'm trying to build a file 'file.ext' with a compiler which I'll call 'comp' (located at ~/code/myComp/bin/ using SCons on Ubuntu 18.04. I get an error message saying -

```
        comp file.ext -o file.out
        sh: 1: comp: not found
        scons: *** [file.out] Error 127
        scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

However, when I copy & paste the exact same build line into the terminal, the compiler is found & the build succeeds without issue. The SCons environment has the correct value for the system PATH - I set the PATH in the construction environment by explicitly copying value in the external environment using os.environ['PATH'] and passing the value into the Environment constructor.

I create my build environment using /bin/bash and feeding a small shell script that defines where the compiler lives etc...
I'm wondering if this has anything to do with SCons using /bin/sh i.e. dash instead of /bin/bash internally. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Often the "not found" error on line 1 means the shell interpreter can't be found. I'm having trouble envisioning your setup. Can you provide more details (SConstruct, build env script, comp)?

Comment: Is comp a binary, or a shell script?

Comment: does it work if you give the full path to SCons for comp?

Comment: comp is a binary.

Comment: If I supply the full path to comp in SCon, it works without issue.

Comment: possibly the environment PATH is getting overwritten here in SCons?: https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/src/engine/SCons/Platform/posix.py#L94 Could you provide a Minimal Reproduce-able example so we can really see what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provided, I'll just show you a working example and maybe you can compare to how your environment is setup.

Here is an example SConstruct:

```py
import os, stat

# arbitrary location for fake compiler
f = open("/tmp/comp.sh", "w")
f.write("""echo "COMPILER COMPILING!"
cat $1 > out.ext
echo " is compiled" >> out.ext""")
f.close()

# make sure its executable
os.chmod("/tmp/comp.sh", stat.S_IRWXU) 

# fake input file
f = open("out.in", "w")
f.write("code")
f.close()

# add arbitrary path to environment
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ":/tmp"

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
#env = Environment() # not setting the ENV causes sh: 1: comp.sh: not found
env.Command('out.ext', 'out.in', 'comp.sh $SOURCE')
```

Heres the output I get if I use the `env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)` line

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
comp.sh out.in
COMPILER COMPILING!
scons: done building targets.
```

Heres the output I get if I uncomment and use the `env = Environment()` line and comment out the previous line

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
comp.sh out.in
sh: 1: comp.sh: not found
scons: *** [out.ext] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```